# Microsoft Edge misplaced brackets in RTL language like Hebrew

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, microsoft-edge

I have the following text for which I want to save translation in my app: "Some Number (generated on save).

Google translate does this:

[image]

So the translation in RTL Hebrew (correctly translated and sentence wrapped by google) is: מספר כלשהו (נוצר בשמירה)

Pasting this in my text box in Chrome or Firefox is correct:

[image]

But when I do the same in Microsoft Edge, the bracket comes misplaced:

[image]

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to test the issue with the **MS Edge 89.0.774.68** version and I can reproduce the said issue.

I noticed that when I try to paste the **מספר כלשהו (נוצר בשמירה)**  Hebrew text in the textbox that does not have any CSS applied shows the bracket misplaced.

Test result with the **MS Edge 89.0.774.68**:

[image]

Further, I test this issue with the MS Edge Canary, Dev, and Beta versions.

I noticed that the issue is fixed in the **MS Edge 91.0.851.0** version.

Test result with the **MS Edge 91.0.851.0**:

[image]

When you update the **MS Edge browser** to the **91.x** version then this issue will get fixed.

Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

That's an effect of pasting right-to-left text into an `<input>` that is using left-to-right writing direction. I'm seeing this effect in Chrome 88 on macOS, so perhaps your Chrome has an extension or global style that automatically sets the writing direction.

You can either set the `<input>`'s [`dir` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir):

```html
<input dir="rtl" value="מספר כלשהו (נוצר בשמירה)">
```

Or apply a class that sets the [`direction` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction):

```html
<input class="rtl" value="מספר כלשהו (נוצר בשמירה)">
```

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

It's also common to apply writing direction globally at the document level:

```css
html {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

...or on the `<html>` tag:

```html
<html dir="rtl">
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

.ltr {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>dir=rtl</legend>
  <input dir="rtl" value="מספר כלשהו (נוצר בשמירה)">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>dir=ltr</legend>
  <input value="מספר כלשהו (נוצר בשמירה)">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>style.direction=ltr</legend>
  <input class="ltr" value="מספר כלשהו (נוצר בשמירה)">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>style.direction=rtl</legend>
  <input class="rtl" value="מספר כלשהו (נוצר בשמירה)">
</fieldset>
```